# Gcloud service with Gunicorn and webdriver keeps terminating. Possible memory error?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, gcloud

I am attempting to run Selenium webdriver as a Gcloud service. It keeps terminating with what appears to be a memory problem.

I have increased the memory to 4Gb with two servers, which should be more than enough to initialise web driver, which is all I am trying to do at the moment.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import json
import math
import os.path
import time


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from flask import Flask

# deploy google service
# https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service
#
#
#  Service URL:  webdriver
app = Flask(__name__)

# driver = webdriver.Chrome()

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)  # this is the error 


@app.route("/")
def collect_data():
    # This will collect and build JSON... later

    game_json = [["One A", "One B"],
                 ["Two A", "Two B", "Two C", "Two D", "Two E", "Two F"],
                 ["Three A", "Three B", "Three C", "Three D"]]
    return game_json


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)))
```

Requirements.txt

```
Chromedriver-binary==122.0.6237.0.0
Flask==3.0.0
gunicorn==21.2.0
Werkzeug==3.0.1
Selenium==4.16.0
```

Relevant log messages appear to be

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/cnb/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/120.0.6099.109/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

and

DEFAULT 2024-01-11T00:50:12.755795Z [2024-01-11 00:50:12 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:10)
DEFAULT 2024-01-11T00:50:13.955768Z [2024-01-11 00:50:13 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:10) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?
```

I have tried various permutations of requirements.txt,
I'm not sure if I need Chromedriver in there, but there it is.

I've also tried the 'pip freeze > requirements.txt'
It didn't help, and is not in the example above.

I have also tried increasing the memory in the google cloud console to 4Gib and 2 cpus.
More than plenty, right?

Ive tried seaching stack overflow, it seems increase memory is the general recommendation, but it's not working.

Help is gratefully accepted

Update 13/01/2024

This has been deeply frustrating. I have a series of new software platforms and diagnostics. Each of which does not work.
I can't further diagnose the memory problem with the google service container.
I've set memory to 32Gb, just to see. Still the same error status code 127.
Soemthing is fundamentally wrong.  I'm just doing a webdriver.Chrome() initialisation.

I have tried installing Docker with pyCharm, it cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Docker.exe is not found.
I have uninstalled, reinstalled, restarted.  Same result. All the attempted searches have not revealed the problem

I have tried installing Docker desktop.  Docker Engine stopped. It does not start.  I get an unexpected WSL error
I've tried "reset to factory defaults"
No change. Docker is dead.

I've tried the instructions at the Diagnose & Feedback.
This is in the log: [FAIL] DD0025: are WSL distros installed? WSL Distribution docker-desktop is missing
I've tried the instructions here:

This told me it might be the VPN.  https://forums.docker.com/t/can-not-get-docker-desktop-win-to-start/138008
Disabled the VPN.  No change.

At this point, I am none the wiser.

I've got nothing with which to proceed.
I have to walk away.

Environment.  Windows 11, pycharm PyCharm 2023.2.5 (Community Edition)
[...]
Non-Bundled Plugins:
com.jetbrains.edu (2023.11-2023.2-1311)
Docker (232.10227.13)

Comment: Browser-based libraries use lots of memory. The error message indicates a memory problem. Suggestion: Run the container locally with Docker and measure the memory requirements. `docker stats` will help: [document](https://www.docker.com/blog/how-to-monitor-container-memory-and-cpu-usage-in-docker-desktop/). Search for `container/memory/usage` and `container/memory/utilizations` in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-run).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.  It will take me.  I'll have a look into Docker, another new technology to learn.  It will take me a while to get it all done.  Thanks again.

Comment: I've tried installing docker for pycharm.  It has not worked. Also tried docker deskop.  Also failed.  I've tried increasing the memory for the service to 32Gb to see what would happen.  No change.  I'm out of ideas.  I have updated the main question with further details.

Comment: You have a collection of problems and not just one. Break your problems into individual solvable parts. Ignore PyCharm for now. 1) Get WSL2 working on Windows (assuming you have the professional version, if not upgrade). 2) Get Docker working without PyCharm. 3) Learn how to use Docker to build containers.

Comment: As an alternative, look into using a Google Compute Engine instance for your development system. You do not need WSL. Docker is easy to install and set up. Your VM is in the cloud which makes many development tasks easier.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and support.  In breaking the problems into solvable parts, the base problem is the google CLI memory issue, that's where I want to focus my effort.  The problems with Docker and WSL are secondary, I'm only looking to them for diagnosis.  I like the idea of the Google Compute Engine as it's a different angle to hit it from. I also wonder if I have incorrectly set up the google cloud service in some way, to cause this error. The code above works if I remove the selenium webdriver references, and just let it return the hard coded json.

Comment: I'm going to have a 24 hour (or more break), these problems are much better approached the next day with some sleep and passive think time.  Earlier, I had a [Dennis Denuto moment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Wdpsen39Bo) .  I need a break.

Comment: Gooogle cloud service, not CLI...

Comment: Using Docker is not secondary. That is a necessary, almost mandatory, tool to develop Cloud Run applications. I would not even attempt to build a Cloud Run service without Docker. Sort of like saying, I will build a house, but I will not learn how to use hammers or saws.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I really appreciate it.  Using Google Compute Engine, it looks like I am up for not-insignificant costs for a hobby project. I am going to abandon this for now, and come back some time later. I need to 1) find a way to get Docker working on my local machine. It should be much simpler that it apparently is; and 2) Understand why webdriver is not instantiating. The logs indicate memory, but I wonder if it is a setup problem. I'm an old school developer trying to learn new tricks... Again, I appreciate you taking your time to help. I need to rethink my approach.